# Empty json object when read text file

Tags: python, json, text

I'm testing a python script with text data. Able to run the script and return valid json file if the text include in the script but I got empty json object when run the script and with separate text file.

The output only empty json file

```
{
  "ospf": []
}
```

The code below return empty json object when run it with read text file

```
import json

result = {}
l = []

with open('data.txt') as myf:
   for i in myf:
     if i:
        p = [parameter for parameter in i.split("*")]
        for line, x in enumerate(p[0].split("\n")):
            if x and "Ls id" in x:
                ls_id, ip = x.split(": ")
                ls_id = ls_id.strip()
                ip = ip.strip()
        for y in p[1:]:
            if y and "P-2-P" in y:
                temp = {ls_id:ip}
                for items in y.split("\n"):
                    try:
                        key, value = items.split(": ")
                        key = key.strip()
                        value = value.strip()
                        temp[key] = value
                    except ValueError:
                       pass
                l.append(temp)
result["ospf"] = l
print (json.dumps(result,indent=2))

with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(result, json_file)
```

When executed the code below ok with the text data include as data..no problem

```
import json

data = '''
  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.1.1.2
  Adv rtr   : 1.1.1.2
  Ls age    : 201
  Len       : 84
  Link count: 5
   * Link ID: 1.1.1.2
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 1.1.1.4
     Data   : 192.168.100.34
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 1
   * Link ID: 192.168.100.33
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 1.1.1.1
     Data   : 192.168.100.53
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 1
   * Link ID: 192.168.100.54
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Medium

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.1.1.1
  Adv rtr   : 1.1.1.1
  Ls age    : 1699
  Len       : 96
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 80008d72
  chksum    : 0x16fc
  Link count: 6
   * Link ID: 1.1.1.1
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 1.1.1.1
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 12
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 1.1.1.3
     Data   : 192.168.100.26
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 192.168.100.25
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 1.1.1.2
     Data   : 192.168.100.54
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 192.168.100.53
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium'''

import json

result = {}
l = []
for i in data.split("\n\n"):
    if i:
        p = [parameter for parameter in i.split("*")]
        for line, x in enumerate(p[0].split("\n")):
            if x and "Ls id" in x:
                ls_id, ip = x.split(": ")
                ls_id = ls_id.strip()
                ip = ip.strip()
        for y in p[1:]:
            if y and "P-2-P" in y:
                temp = {ls_id:ip}
                for items in y.split("\n"):
                    try:
                        key, value = items.split(": ")
                        key = key.strip()
                        value = value.strip()
                        temp[key] = value
                    except ValueError:
                       pass
                l.append(temp)
result["ospf"] = l
print (json.dumps(result,indent=2))

with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(result, json_file)
```

I'm not sure where i make wrong. Please advise me further. Thank you.

Comment: Iterating over a file produces **lines**, but your inline-string code works by **clauses** separated by blank lines.

Comment: Im copying the same data structure onto text file...but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be to concat the file to one large string. then your code works as expected. This is definetly no clean answer but you could let the rest of your code unchanged.

```
import json

result = {}
l = []

with open('data.txt') as myf:

    a = ''.join(myf)
    for i in a.split("\n\n"):
     if i:
        p = [parameter for parameter in i.split("*")]
        for line, x in enumerate(p[0].split("\n")):
            if x and "Ls id" in x:
                ls_id, ip = x.split(": ")
                ls_id = ls_id.strip()
                ip = ip.strip()
        for y in p[1:]:
            if y and "P-2-P" in y:
                temp = {ls_id:ip}
                for items in y.split("\n"):
                    try:
                        key, value = items.split(": ")
                        key = key.strip()
                        value = value.strip()
                        temp[key] = value
                    except ValueError:
                       pass
                l.append(temp)
result["ospf"] = l
print (json.dumps(result,indent=2))
with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(result, json_file)
```